# DataTables custom date sort on selected input on the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table with a date column (Start date).

The sort is good when I click on the column thanks to the datetime-moment plugin.

BUT, on the dropdown list, the dates are not sorted properly.

This is the test case : http://live.datatables.net/cejizato/4/edit?html,css,js,console,output

I don't know how to sort these values.

I found this code if it's helping ?

```
column.data().unique().sort( function (a,b) {
  return moment(a, "DD/MM/YYYY").unix() - moment(b, "DD/MM/YYYY").unix();
} )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the code you have found inside the code sort() function.

```
initComplete: function ()
{
    this.api().columns().every( function () {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select class="select" data-placeholder="  " multiple data-no-colonne="' + noColonne + '">  </select>')
        .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() );

        column.data().unique().sort(function (a,b) {
            return moment(a, "DD/MM/YYYY").unix() - moment(b, "DD/MM/YYYY").unix();
        }).each(function (d, j) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'" data-no-colonne="' + noColonne + '" data-actions-box="true">'+d+'</option>' );
        });

        noColonne++;
    });
}
```